# Queuing concurrent web service requests in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, web-services, concurrency

I have an application that sends concurrent web service requests. These requests are then processes by a .Net proxy (that has several methods depending on the request). When a request is processed, a SoapLogger Extension class will then log request and response calls.

The issue I have is that some of the web service requests did not receive responses and are stuck. One reason could be threads timed-out. Is there a way that web service method requests can be queued and add a "sleep" parameter to synchronous request? or is a reverse-proxy the last resort?

I am thinking of processing 1 web service synch request at a time and add a sleep parameter on the interface to give time to the asynchronous part to progress while any new incoming request would be queued.

Comment: It sounds like a concurrency problem. Are you sure there is not a bottleneck in the SoapLogger construction ? Are you using singleton instances ? Can you add some code to get a better idea of the problem ?

Comment: Actually we had an issue with the Soap Logger where several processes are trying to write to a single file and was already fixed, and yes singleton instances are implemented. We are still investigating a possible bottleneck in the SoapLogger and one possible solution we had in mind is to queue the processing of web service requests.

Comment: This is an example of one of my Web Methods where I want the request to be queued until a response is returned.. `[WebMethod]
    public allocateServiceResponse allocateService([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute()] allocateService allocateService)
    {
        MyDeploy Deploy = new Adapter();
        allocateServiceResponse Resp = new allocateServiceResponse();

        Resp = MyDeploy.allocateService(allocateService);

        return Resp;
    }`